# It is possible (and normal practice) to byte-compile files other than .emacs?

Tags: emacs, plugins, compilation

I'm using some plugins and I byte-compiled my .emacs but the start up still slow. Do I hava to byte-compile my prlugins too? (for instance, yasnippet.el -> yasnippet.elc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Byte compiled files load up faster so I'd recommend that you byte compile everything as Pascal suggested. I also keep this in my init file so automatically byte compile all the emacs lisp files I edit and save.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook '(lambda () 
               (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'emacs-lisp-byte-compile t t)))   ;; Automatically byte-compile emacs-lisp files upon save
```

Comment: Addictive thing... emacs.. isn't it? :)

Comment: Very helpful. Emacs even tell you how to improve the file. A last question: where do I place the .elc files? Is better to place them ina  folder or in the same folder as their .el?

Comment: I put them in the same directory since otherwise, I'd have to mess with my load-path and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs can feel slow to start up even without any `.emacs` or plugins :)

It is a good idea to compile plug-ins, that's as much time shaved from start-up. Compiling the `.emacs` configuration file is less usual (because it changes more often and is typically small anyway), but why not?

You probably already know this, but `.el` files can be byte-compiled using: M-x byte-compile-file or M-x byte-recompile-directory .

Answer (score 2):

You can use emacs server to speed things up, then it only takes time to start the server the first time.

> The way to start an Emacs server is to run Emacs as a daemon, using the ‘--daemon’ command-line option. When Emacs is started this way, it calls server-start after initialization, and returns control to the calling terminal instead of opening an initial frame; it then waits in the background, listening for edit requests.
>
> Once an Emacs server is set up, you can use a shell command called emacsclient to connect to the existing Emacs process and tell it to visit a file. If you set the EDITOR environment variable to ‘emacsclient’, programs such as mail will use the existing Emacs process for editing.

From: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely find something use here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoRecompile

A great selection of tips for automatically byte-compiling files, when you save them or when you load them, and even caching the compiled files in a certain directory.